# warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'root' [-Wimplicit-int]|

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test{
int data;
struct test *link;
};
struct test *root;
root=(struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

i get error :
warning: data definition has no type or storage class|
warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'root' [-Wimplicit-int]|

Comment: Is that your complete and actual code? You can't call functions in the global scope. Need to call them in a function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call code from global scope in C, use a `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct test{
   int data;
   struct test *link;
};

int main(){
   struct test *root;
   root=(struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));

   //  Then write some meaningful code here
   //  remember to test if root is null and exit if malloc failed

   //  and finally free your allocated memory  
   free(root);
                                                                                                                                                         
}
```